# How to repeatedly add a button using php

Tags: php, button

I am trying to add an "Add to wishlist" button next to every record from a database. If I add the form tags inside the loop it comes up with an error asking to place ";" inside action. If I add the button outside the loop it is shown only once. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: the error I get is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''>' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/sta402/PHP_stuff/CarTemplate/Views/CarList.phtml on line 16` and the underlined part of the code is between the quotation marks after "action" in the form for the button.

```
    <?php require('template/header.phtml') ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    <br>
    <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr><th>Type</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Colour</th><th>Price</th><th>Year</th><th>Picture</th></tr>


       </thead>   
    <tbody> 
        <?php foreach ($view->carDataSet as $carData) {
              echo '<tr> <td>' . $carData->getType() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getMake() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getModel() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getColour() .'</td> <td>' . $carData->getPrice() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getYearOfRegistration() . '</td><td>' . $carData->getPicture() . '</td></tr>';


        } ?>
        <form method="POST" action=''>
            <input type="submit" name="button1"  value="My Button">
        </form>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</form>

<?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're using single quotes (`'`) within a single quote encapsulated string. You can fix this in multiple ways:

1. use double quotes (`"`) inside your string:

   ```
   echo '<form method="POST" action="">
       blablabla
   </form>';
   ```
2. escape the single quotes in your string:

   ```
   echo '<form method="POST" action=\'\'>
       blablabla
   </form>';
   ```
3. use the `heredoc` syntax:

   ```
   echo <<<HTML
   <form method="POST" action=''>
       blablabla
   </form>
   HTML;
   ```
4. exit out of `php` after the `echo` statement:

   ```
   echo ?>
   <form method="POST" action=''>
       blablabla
   </form>
   <?php;
   ```

You can then put the correct `echo` statement in the `foreach loop`:

```
<?php foreach ($view->carDataSet as $carData) {
    echo '<tr> <td>' . $carData->getType() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getMake() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getModel() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getColour() .'</td> <td>' . $carData->getPrice() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getYearOfRegistration() . '</td><td>' . $carData->getPicture() . '</td></tr>';
    //one of the four above options for the button echo statement
} ?>
```

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to correctly learn how to use strings